# Pausing SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading

Im a beginner to GUI and multithreading. I currently have a simulation which runs through a bug moving about in the console. I want to be able to pause the bug using a button. I have two buttons (run and pause) the run button will start the simulation and the pause button should pause it ( or make it sleep for a bit) ive managed to get the run button working but i am then unable to click pause once its running (because its in the same thread i believe) Ive read into it alot but still cant seem to work it out.. any help would be massively appreciated..
//IN MY ACTION LISTENER..

```
else if (E.getSource() == Pause) {
        Worker pauseWorker = new Worker();
        pauseWorker.execute();
```

IN MY NEW WORKER CLASS

```
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

   public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    // System.out.println("Background");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Background running");
    }

    return null;

}
```

}

Comment: This is a different question from [the one suggested as a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668389/java-gui-need-to-pause-a-method-without-freezing-gui-aswell). A background thread has been created, the question here is how to pause it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else if (E.getSource() == Pause) {
    Worker pauseWorker = new Worker();
    pauseWorker.execute();
```

This starts a new worker, does not stop the running one.

Instead, you can keep a reference to the background worker and `cancel()` it when the pause button is pressed. See [SwingWorker.cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#cancel%28boolean%29)

```
else if (E.getSource() == Pause) {
    worker.cancel(true);
}
```

And in the worker class, regularly check if you've been cancelled:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    // System.out.println("Background");
    while(!isCancelled()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Background interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("Background running");
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

If you really do need to pause rather than cancel the worker, you'll have to write your own pause() method and do the administration yourself.

To give you some idea, something like this goes into the worker class then:

```
boolean paused = false;

public void pause() {
    paused = true;
}

public synchronized void resume() {
    paused = false;
    this.notify();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    while(!isCancelled()) {
        if( paused ) {
            System.out.println("Background paused, waiting for resume");
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    wait(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Background interrupted");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Background running");
            // do a chunk of actual work
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: i get an error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method wait(long) from the type Object" on the line              Thread.wait(1000); ?

Comment: i also get an error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method cancel(boolean) from the type SwingWorker<Void,Void>" on the line "else if (E.getSource() == Pause) {
   Worker.cancel(true)" sorry

Comment: You need to store the Worker in a field. So not Worker.cancel() but a field Worker worker. Set it to the worker you create when the run button gets clicked and then do worker.cancel() when the Pause button gets clicked.